# Adobe CQ/AEM Article/Page when created the indicator light shows as published but they are not published

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have weird situation in our test environment where Adobe CQ / AEM Blog articles or pages, when created, automatically shown in CQ5 WCM as published although they are not published (Verified from Publish site).

[image]

Is there a configuration to turn this down so not to mislead us?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently template sets the properties as well.

From CRXDE Lite, navigate to /apps//templates/template1/jcr:content and you should see the configuration to be attached to newly created page (eg. cq:lastReplicatedBy, cq:lastReplicatedAction).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please check in content for your specific page & then look for the replication details of that page. If still no success then unpublish & publish again with monitoring server error log.

For Coding in CQ:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJaXmMtZSCU